# Static function for logging errors

Tags: c#, static-methods

I would like to get some programming knowledge about static functions and its usage. Is it better to add error logging mechanism to a static function? If yes what will be the advantages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the details of [static and instance methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645629%28VS.71%29.aspx). And you should consider making it static if you think you will gain the following advantage.

After [marking members as static], the compiler will emit non-virtual call sites to these members which will prevent a check at runtime for each call that ensures the current object pointer is non-null. This can result in a measurable performance gain for performance-sensitive code. In some cases, the failure to access the current object instance represents a correctness issue.